# mysql warning: Cannot set query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a mysql statement that query a table with 10+ millions of rows, joining other table with even more rows, it all works OK if I select rows within date-range of one month, but as soon as I increase date-range (and I get more results, over 900 results actually) I'm getting a mysql warning from the title of my question, but results are returned.

Anyone knows what this warning even means?

EDIT:

**Warning: Cannot set query. Then here is written my query.**

SOLVED. It was caching problem, after caching is turned off it works.

Comment: please post the warning message

Comment: @krishna: "*I'm getting a mysql warning from the title of my question*".  One would imagine that's "*Cannot set query*", then.

Comment: was it displaying only `mysql warning` ? also post your sql query

Comment: @krishna edited my question. it just says Warning: cannot set query, and then it writes my select statement.

Comment: Post your sql query also.then only we can help you.

Comment: added query, but I don't thing it's anything to do with query itself...

Comment: **Don't paraphrase error messages.** "Warning: cannot set query," is not the error message it gave you. The error message was much longer. It included a line number. We need the entire message, and you need to tell us which line in your code is that line number.

Comment: @AndyLester I'm not paraphrasing, it's the error it shows on my screen. Actually thank you, you just made me realise it's not a mysql, but a php warning due to caching. After I turned caching off, it works

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing 2nd table name from the query members

so please try update FROM clause

```
FROM members_data
```

to

```
FROM members_data, members
```

Comment: it's LEFT JOIN-ed with table members

Comment: It looks like you are not following left join query syntax ON members_dates.memberID = members_data.id both tables must be different check here [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Sorry I'm not following, those are 2 different tables.